# How to add css to login,register and logout link separately?

Tags: magento

I am trying to have different css for login register and login links. But as they are being added using template_links block and they are automatically rendered and no template file for specific one, I am unable to achieve this.

```
 <block type="page/template_links" name="account.links" as="accountLinks"/>
```

At the moment I tried changing the css but obviously css rules are getting assigned to all of it at the same time.

How can I achieve this please suggest something. Thank you

can I do that using layout?

```
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="account.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>2</position></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>

<!--
Load this update on every page when customer is logged out
-->

    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="account.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Login</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>Login</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>1</position></action>
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl" ifconfig="enterprise_invitation/general/registration_required_invitation"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
            <!-- <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /><title>register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position><li/><a/><before_text> or </before_text><after_text>.</after_text></action> -->
        </reference>
        <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"></remove>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
        <remove name="top.menu" />
    </customer_logged_out>

<!--
Layout for customer login page
-->

    <customer_account_login translate="label">
        <label>Customer Account Login Form</label>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="customer/form_login" name="customer_form_login" template="customer/form/login.phtml"/> 
        </reference>
    </customer_account_login>
```

current theme links look like this

[image]

------EDIT-----

After placing class in aparam It is still applying same old css rules as in the html showing no class element. I have place the .logout-link class in the same theme in custom and style.css but still no luck. It is not finding this class and not even it is showing in chrome developer tools.

```
<customer_logged_in>
<reference name="account.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
        <label>Log Out</label>
        <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
        <title>Log Out</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>2</position>
        <aParams>class="logout-link"</aParams>
        </action>
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
</reference>
```

```
<div class="header-links-wrapper">
        <ul class="links">
                    <li class="first last"><a href="http://www.ubt.com/index.php/customer/account/logout/" title="Log Out">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a class with the `addLink` method using the following:

```
<liParams/>
<aParams>class="My Class Name"</aParams>
<beforeText/>
<afterText/>
```

So for example, to add a class to your logout link, you can do this:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer">
    <label>Log Out</label>
    <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/>
    <title>Log Out</title><prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>2</position>
    <liParams/>
    <aParams>class="logout-link"</aParams>
    <beforeText/>
    <afterText/>
</action>
```

Then you just add a css definition for `logout-link`

Comment: I wish there were a way to amend the core link without modifying core layout XML, but this is the cleanest & best path.

Comment: I was assuming the XML he posted was a part of your custom Magento template, which would override the default XML files.

Comment: Not sure. I just wish it were possible to `<action method="updateLink" block="top.links"><args><aParam>class="foo"</aParam></args></action>`, you know?

Comment: Ehh, that's just Magento for you.  Just have to go with the way it's designed.  We can only hope that future iterations make tasks such as adding classes to links inside of blocks a bit more straightforward.

Comment: After implementing this it is still showing the old rules please check I have edited the question. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Clear the `block_html` cache.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good idea to disable the Magento cache when you're doing template development.

Comment: Found the problem. It was not rendering because I didn't put <liParams/> as It's showing in my edit code. It believe it the <li> tag and without implementing I can not jump to <a> straightaway. Thank you for Axel and for looking into it.